# Customize django admin select foreign key popup

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin

I need to customize popup for select raw_id_field foreign key

I have my admin like this:

```
class SecondMyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    switch_date = models.DateField()
    old_value = models.ForeignKey(SecondMyModel)


class MyModelAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta(object):
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('old_value', 'switch_date')


@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelAdminForm
    list_display = ('id', 'old_value', 'switch_date')
    ordering = ('switch_date',)

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('old_value', 'switch_date'),
            'classes': ('suit-tab', 'suit-tab-general'),
        }),
    )
    raw_id_fields = ('old_value',)
```

When I'm trying to add new MyModel I need to select 'old_value'.

How can I change select foreign key popup for having opportunity to select 'old_value' by click on its id field or its name field? (not only 'id' or only 'name')